# After training a NuSVC, can I retrieve rho?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I'm using nu-SVM for classification (`sklearn.svm.NuSVC`). After having trained it, is there any way of retrieving the computed "rho" parameter (see Eq. 52ff, 64 in http://www.kernel-machines.org/papers/tr-31-1998.ps.gz)?

Comment: I don't see a rho parameter in the documentation. Maybe the documentation calls it by another name. Do you see anything similar to it in [this list](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.NuSVC.html) of attributes?

Comment: No. I have taken a look at the list before asking. If it goes under a different name, then it is well hidden. If not, is there an undocumented method or a workaround?

Comment: Well, there's the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13a/sklearn/svm/_classes.py#L675). You can scan through it to find something like equation 52ff.